# Can't upgrade WSL Ubuntu - how do I get xvfb-run?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xvfb

I am running Xenial Ubuntu in Windows 10 subsystem linux system. I need to install `xvfb-run` but I can not because it is not in the repo. I guess I need to upgrade Ubuntu, but `do-release-upgrade` finds no new versions.

How can I get `xvfb-run` running on my Xenial Ubuntu in WSL?

Comment: You don't.  WSL doesn't come with the same X layers as a full Ubuntu version.  There's also no newer WSL than 16.04.  If I may ask, why *do* you need `xvfb-run`?

Comment: I am a front end developer. I need to run E2E tests. I need xvfb-run so I can run the browser headless. I haven't found a away for the WSL to access the GUI Windows chrome.

Comment: You can always drop WSL and install normal Ubuntu to VM or alongside Windows or instead of Windows.

Comment: In WSL the command is `sudo apt install xvfb`

Comment: I get connection failed...  I think the repos are to old

Comment: I can't tell ya.  They could be.  Try running `sudo apt update` first.  I just installed it on mine and I get the `xvfb-run` command.

Comment: I did, no success

Comment: You might have a different problem then if you are getting connection failed.  Can you run `ping www.google.com`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/761 as it could be an Anti-Virus blocking the internet or maybe a firewall issue.  Just some suggestions.

Comment: @dman it's currently not possible either way. (https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2356).  The closest you could get is to run XMing and try and SSH to the WSL layer, and use *that* to run X apps through X Server via XMing or something.  Direct GUI applications in WSL isn't a high priority based on that bug.  However, `xvfb-run` directly in WSL won't help.  I would suggest you use an Ubuntu VM though, to do E2E tests and front-end devlopment tests, rather than try to use WSL to get a 'linux' version of a web browser to do testing.

Comment: @ThomasWard You CAN run any docker image on WSL - https://github.com/RoliSoft/WSL-Distribution-Switcher . Many of the docker images are fairly minimal and may need to be configured, and I have tried many, but all the ones I tried are working. Running graphical apps, however, is limited with variable degrees of success.

Comment: @Panther docker images roll their own X though, and sorta bypass that.  I wasnt talking about docker images, we were talking about `xvfb-run` which is part of a directly run X Server within Linux...

Comment: @ThomasWard - I understand about X, or wayland as the case may be, I was replying to your comment that your comment "There's also no newer WSL than 16.04. " . That is simply not the case, you can run Ubuntu all the way up to 17.10 if you so desire , see the link I gave you.